# Need help on implementing this Use-Case Scenario in NetSuite Oracle

Tags: e-commerce, integration, netsuite, suitecommerce

I am very new to E-Commerce World.
I have a use case scenario that I want to Implement in Oracle NetSuite.
But I am not sure how to move forward with it.

**Use-Case Scenario:**
A Sales Order has a few Line Items & Among them, a few are out of stock.
The 3PL currently I am dealing with accepts only one Unique Sales Order ID as an Identifier.
I want to fulfill the items that are currently in stock and Later on, when the Inventory gets updated I want to fulfill the remaining Items back-ordered in the Sales Order.
But the fulfillment should happen only after the customer has paid for the Items.

Can anyone let me know? How can I achieve this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need some customisation to achieve this.  I don't know the full set of processes you're working with, but as a general approach, I would suggest the following:

- Set up a payment term that says the customer must prepay.
- Set up a script to run on your fulfilments, handle "prepay" customers.

You'll also want to check your settings in Setup > Accounting > Accounting Preferences > Order Management.  Look for the option on sales orders and fulfilment.  You'll probably want to default your fulfilment to available quantity only.  You may want to prevent overage on your fulfilments.

When the script executes on your fulfilment, it should execute "before load".  The script will need to check the sales order it's fulfilling.  If the term is "prepay", the script should then check if a payment has been made against the sales order.  You'll potentially need to consider deposits and paid invoices.  If the script finds no payments, then it should block the fulfilment.

I'm working on the assumption that you will create a fulfilment with a "Picked" status to send to your warehouse.  When they confirm the "goods-out", you will want some sort of feedback loop from your 3PL to set the fulfilment to "Shipped" and update your tracking numbers.

I hope this helps.

Mark

Comment: Hi Mark, Thank you. Appreciate your help. Can you please provide me with some references or let me know how can I create the payment terms with prepay on Sales Order ?

Comment: @AnekPorwal, payment terms are available by navigating Setup > Accounting > Accounting Lists.  From the dropdown, select "Terms".  You'll need to create a term with the name "Prepayment".  Use this in your workflow to help block fulfillments.